# What is wrong with org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect?

Tags: hibernate

What is wrong with org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect (it's depricated) and what should I use instead in hibernate configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQLDialect.html), PostgreSQL82Dialect needs to be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

as per hibernate docs

```
PostgreSQL81Dialect:    An SQL dialect for Postgres 
For discussion of BLOB support in Postgres, as of 8.4, have a peek at http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/84/binary-data.html.

PostgreSQL82Dialect:    An SQL dialect for Postgres 8.2 and later, adds support for "if exists" when dropping tables

PostgreSQLDialect:  Deprecated. use PostgreSQL82Dialect instead
```

***PostgreSQLDialect:   Deprecated. use PostgreSQL82Dialect instead***